# Route is not found with empty RoutePrefix on controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2, routeattribute

I have someones code here and I do not understand it above all the "empty" RoutePrefix on the controller.

I call the url in the browser like this:

http://localhost/TestService/TestAccess/FindProducts/de/2/product/5

I get a 404 for this controller + action:

```
[RoutePrefix("")]
public class TestAccessController : ApiController
{

    [Route("{country}/{brandlist}/product/{databaseID:int}")]
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> FindProducts(String country, String brandlist, int databaseID)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

That is the route setup:

```
 config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
 config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(name: "Default", routeTemplate: "{controller}" );
```

What route do I have to enter in the browser url bar to trigger my FindProducts endpoint without changing the existing code?

Comment: Do you have a RouteConfig class? If so, please can you let us know what is in it?

Comment: My route setup is above, just have a look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The route attribute is absolute - it doesn't take the controller name unless you specify it in the route (or set a route prefix at the controller level).

Try changing your route to

```
[Route("TestAccess/FindProducts/{country}/{brandlist}/product/{databaseID:int}")]
```

Edit

Or try to change the url to...

```
http://localhost/de/2/product/5
```

or possibly 
    http://localhost/TestService/de/2/product/5

Comment: I made my question more clear: What route do I have to enter in the browser url bar to trigger my FindProducts endpoint without changing the existing code?

Comment: possibly... yes it works :-) thanks! I gotta ask my colleagues when they are back why they made an empty route on the controller...

Comment: Good, glad to hear it:)